# Webforms: Is it possible to set maximal value for Number in relation to another Number value?

Tags: webforms

I am new in Drupal...

In webforms I use `Number` field to set age of person:

**How old are you?** [Number] /min 10, max 100/

**When did you smoke for the first time?** [Number] /min 10, max *`here should be the value of the previous number.`*

Is it possible to set it somehow in Webform GUI, or the only by the code?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try making the age a drop-down with the given range and then [webform conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) becomes an easy, ready to use option.

Many other ways to get this done but this is probably the most straightforward imho.

Comment: the most important part for me is, that there are more ways than none. I do not want to exploit the people here, I will try myself to find out. Thanx

Comment: In that case, the drop down is one. ;) Others involve additional modules and/or code depending on particulars. Happy to take the answer further if it helps.